Scam on defi wallet
I invested and crossed 8788 usdt on defi wallet. After some days i got a msg of 16 ETH contract pool reward msg. I click on it for claim. Then my withdrawal balance was shown 16 ETH. I tried to withdraw money. But it was not possible. Then i contacted the help chat. Help chat was guided me to contact to telegram number. When i contact that telegram number i came to know i have to pay 11K USD again within 6 days to withdraw reward. I was surprised. I didn't add money yet. I am thinking it is scam. Could you please advice on this please

It absolutely is. The chances of seeing your money back are as close to zero as it gets, but do check out I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum or Uniswap. What to do?

Sorry to say this you’ve been scammed, the same thing also happen to me, I lost 277 usdt in the same process I was told to deposit 2000 usdt to claim back my money wish isn’t possible.
